# Reference to same instance in unittest (Not creating new instance when an object is called)

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, oop

Background: 
I created a class to extract info from google. This class searches the search term and suggest correction if there is any spelling error with the search term.

```
class gs:
    url_part1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="
    key = "some_key"
    cse = 'some_key'
    suggestion = 'None'

def __init__(self, search):
    self.search = search
    self.url = gs.url_part1 + gs.key + gs.cse + self.search
    #gs.suggestion = 'None'

def get_suggestion(self):
    r = requests.get(url=self.url)
    r_json = r.json()
    if 'spelling' in r_json.keys():
        gs.suggestion = r_json.get('spelling').get('correctedQuery')
    return gs.suggestion
```

For example if I search for paytn (correct name is paytm) then this class suggestion correction for paytn which is paytm

```
gs_1 = gs(search='paytn')
suggestion_1 = gs_1.get_suggestion()
print(suggestion_1) #suggestion for incorrect name
'paytm'
```

Instead of searching for paytn if I search for 'paytm' then gs class suggests nothing.

```
gs_2 = gs(search='paytm')
suggestion_2 = gs_2.get_suggestion()
print(suggestion_2) #no suggestion for correct name
'None'
```

Now while creating unittest case for gs class I observed a very strange behavior. **self.gs_2** is picking up the the values from **self.gs_1**
and failing the below test.

```
from search import gs
import unittest

class TestSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.gs_1 = gs(search='paytn')
        self.gs_2 = gs(search='paytm')


    def test_get_suggestion(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.gs_1.get_suggestion(), 'paytm')
        self.assertEqual(self.gs_2.get_suggestion(), 'None')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Upon inspection it is clear that self.gs_2 is acquiring value from first instance of class gs. Please refer to the output below

```
import search
suggestion 1 in setUp paytm
suggestion 2 in setUp paytm
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_suggestion (test.TestSearch)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\YBL\test.py", line 15, in test_get_suggestion
    self.assertEqual(self.gs_2.get_suggestion(), 'None')
AssertionError: 'paytm' != 'None'
- paytm
+ None


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 3.028s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Can anyone help me to understand

1) whether my understanding is correct or not ?

2) Why it is getting values from gs_1 instead of creating a new instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class gs:
    url_part1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="
    key = "some_key"
    cse = 'some_key'

    def __init__(self, search):
        self.search = search
        self.url = gs.url_part1 + gs.key + gs.cse + self.search
        self.suggestion = 'None'

    def get_suggestion(self):
        r = requests.get(url=self.url)
        r_json = r.json()
        if 'spelling' in r_json.keys():
            self.suggestion = r_json.get('spelling').get('correctedQuery')
        return self.suggestion
```

You used `suggestion` in `gs` (same for the whole class), rather than `self.suggestion` that is instance-specific. You can see it in a way you accessed the value - `gs.suggestion` means it belongs to `gs`, `self.suggestion` means it belongs to the current instance that was passed to the method. ;)

In your case, 1st pass overwrote the `gs.suggestion` and the 2nd didn't, so it returned the previous value.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. If I use gs.suggestion Will I get the same result ? I have seen the self.suggestion and gs.suggestion giving me the same result. But self.suggestion is instance specific and gs.suggestion is class specific. So using gs.suggestion won't let one instance overrides its value. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Could you clarify your comment? I can't understand what you mean, you seem to understand but later say that "gs.suggestion won't let one instance overrides its value" which is completely opposite?

Comment: `I have seen the self.suggestion and gs.suggestion giving me the same result.` Depending on order, yes. And I could fix `get_suggestion` to pass the test, but if you do the suggestions together, and search itself only later, the `gs.suggestion` would be only the last suggestion.

Comment: My question is why it is not overriding when I created gs_1 and gs_2  before unittesting?(see above: the values are as expected)

Comment: In first comment: I was asking if I use gs.suggestion instead of self.suggestion I am getting correct result for unittesting case. Is there any harm is using gs.suggestion. As per my knowledge self.variable first look value in instance space and then in class space while class.varable look value in class space. If I use class.variable and create multiple instances, is any instance (suggestion) override the value for other instance (suggestion) ?